# Java methods combine a list of arrays: variable number of arguments

Tags: java, arrays, methods, variadic-functions

A method to combine a list of arrays: variable number of arrays.
Method signature

```
public static <T> T[] combine(T[] ... a) {
    ...
} 

byte[] a = [];
byte[] b = [];
byte[] c = [];
combine(a, b, c);   // compiling error
```

What is the right way to define the method signature for variable number of arrays. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you get downvoted. It's a valid question.

Comment: Even if the three arrays had non-primitive elements, how would you create a new array of `T` to combine them into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you cannot substitute primitive types with `T`.

Try using the wrapper class `Byte`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Byte[] a = new Byte[]{0x0};
  Byte[] b = a;
  Byte[] c = a;
  combine(a, b, c); 
}
public static <T> T[] combine(T[] ... a) {
  //do your magic here
}
```

Of course this code does not combine the arrays, but the method call compiles.